# how to use slug to 'objects.filter' retrieve data through a many-to-many class

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-queryset, slug

I'm new to django and coding, so in my head with this problem, i've got two directions that i have no idea if whether either will be the right solution.

So I have in `model.py` three classes `Recipe` `Ingredient` and `IngredientAmount` where,

- `Recipe` has a `ManyToManyField` to connect to `Ingredient` and has `SlugField` to be picked up by my `recipe_detail.html` page using a Detail function-based-view.
- `IngredientAmount` acts as a 'through' class so to speak and has `Recipe` and `Ingredient` as a `ForeignKey`

here is my `model.py`:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(
        r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+', 'Only alphabet characters and spaces are allowed.')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True,
                             validators=[alphanumeric])
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Ingredient', through='IngredientAmount', related_name='recipes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('recipe:recipe_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class IngredientAmount(models.Model):
    SINGLE = 1
    DOUBLE = 2
    TRIPLE = 3
    AMOUNT_CHOICES = (
        (SINGLE, 'Single'),
        (DOUBLE, 'Double'),
        (TRIPLE, 'Triple'),
    )

    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        'Recipe', related_name='ingredient_amounts', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(
        'Ingredient', related_name='ingredient_amounts', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,blank=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(choices=AMOUNT_CHOICES, default=SINGLE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Recipe = {self.recipe}, Ingredient = {self.ingredient}, Amount = {self.amount}'
```

I can get my `recipe_detail.html` to show the `{{ recipe.title }}` and `{{ recipe.description }}` through grabbing the slug and using the `context={'recipe':recipe}`

```
def recipeDetail(request, slug):
    recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, slug=slug)

    # r = Recipe.objects.get(slug=slug)
    # related_ingredients = r.ingredients_set.all() --> related_ingredients = r.recipes.all() -- will work because of 'related_name' in my Recipe model?
    
    return render(request, 'recipe/recipe_detail.html', {'recipe': recipe, 'related_ingredients': related_ingredients})
```

so what I want to do is get the 'recipe' title, 'ingredient' name and 'amount' using `context={related_ingredients': related_ingredients}` from IngredientAmount.
I can do this with pk in the shell like so:

```
>>> ia = IngredientAmount.objects.filter(recipe_id=3)
>>> ia
<QuerySet [<IngredientAmount: Recipe = pumpkin with rice, Ingredient = pumpkin, Amount = 1>, <IngredientAmount: Recipe = pumpkin with rice, Ingredient = rice, Amount = 
1>]>
```

but i want to be able to grab it by its slug 'pumpkin-with-rice'.

so going back to my 2 possible solution in my head (which might be completely off) - and posed as a question:

1. is there a way to retrieve a related_object like `recipe` from `Recipe` model by calling it's slug via my m2m-through class like my `IngredientAmount` class (with/without related_name)?

where i've been looking to derive this: [related_objects in m2m](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) and [m2m-through class](https://www.revsys.com/tidbits/tips-using-djangos-manytomanyfield/)

2. or do i have to make like a `SlugField` in my `IngredientAmount` class to somehow change my recipe_id into slug? if so, how do i do that?

i hope all of that makes sense. i would appreciate anything to just point me into the right direction. im quite clueless how to go about this. theres quite a bit on using objects.filter(id=[num]) and quite some bit on how to retrieve data as `_set` from an m2m - but no idea when it comes to as a slug and with an m2m-through model. i apologise in advance if my code or question is rubbish - let me know if i can clarify anything. thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you can do this:`ia = IngredientAmount.objects.filter(recipe__slug='pumpkin-with-rice')` with a double underscore. This is described in the Django docs under [Field Lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups).

Comment: @evergreen mate, this was exactly what i needed. i didnt realise `field__lookuptype=value` also include `__slug` thanks for the help!